# 1 %% 0.1 = 0.1 AND 1 %% 0.2 = 0.2?

Tags: r, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Am I missing a thing or a bug in the base package?

I am running on **R-2.15.2, on Win 7-32**

> x %% y    modulus (x mod y) 5 %% 2 is 1
>
> from : http://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html

---

```
>  1 %% 0.1
[1] 0.1

>  1 %% 0.2
[1] 0.2
```

Both of them must be 0.

The below examples works as expected.
For example:

> 1 %% 0.15

must be 0.1 ( 1.0 = 6 x 0.15 + **0.1**)

---

```
>  1 %% 0.11  # expected result 
[1] 0.01

>  1 %% 0.15
[1] 0.1

>  1 %% 0.3
[1] 0.1

>  1 %% 0.4
[1] 0.2

> 1 %% 0.5
[1] 0
```

Comment: You should include an _explanation_ of your expected result in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I cannot reproduce this using R version 2.15.1 running on x86_64.

If that's what happens in your environment, this almost certainly has to do with the fact that neither `0.1` nor `0.2` can be represented exactly using binary floating-point arithmetic:

```
> sprintf("%.20f", 0.1)
[1] "0.10000000000000000555"
> sprintf("%.20f", 0.2)
[1] "0.20000000000000001110"
```

The documentation for `%%` has the following to say:

> `%%` and `x %/% y` can be used for non-integer `y`, e.g. `1 %/% 0.2`, but the results are subject to representation error and so may be platform-dependent. Because the IEC 60059 representation of `0.2` is a binary fraction slightly larger than `0.2`, the answer to `1 %/% 0.2` should be `4` but most platforms give `5`.

There are many other similar pitfalls having to do with the properties of floating-point arithmetic (not just in R). The classic paper on the subject is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: (+1) for the excellent link. I'm going to have to bookmark this as this sort of stuff often comes up here on SO under R tag.

Comment: (+1) for the link and the answer. But i cannot reach %% documentation.